# I want to Save only Time instead of Date and time in coredata objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsdate

I want like hh:mm:ss (10:45:32) instead of like 2017-10-24 10:45:32 +0600, how to make it possible in Core Data?

```
- (IBAction)SaveTasks:(UIButton *)sender
{

    [dateformater setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];

    NSDate *date = [dateformater dateFromString:datepictxt.text];

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = ((AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]).persistentContainer.viewContext;

    NSManagedObject *entityNameObj = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Tasks" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    [entityNameObj setValue:tasks.text forKey:@"taskname"];
    [entityNameObj setValue:date forKey:@"date"];

    [((AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]) saveContext];

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![context save:&error])
    {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);

    }else {
        NSLog(@"Your Data has been Saved!");
    }



}
```

Comment: If you want to save the `NSString` of "10:45:32" then save it as a string... don't convert it to a `NSDate` object.

Comment: Then how can I compare with time.

Comment: So Saving only Time is not possible..

Comment: OK - if you want to compare "time" instead of "string" then you need to understand what a Date is. You're getting a string from `datepictxt` and you want to save that as "time"? Try explaining what you *want to do*...

Comment: I am making a app which Save TaskName, TaskDate, and Tasktime...Then I want to Notify them if the time comes(meets) like Alarm..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a CoreData Entity with a Date type, than Date is by default an NSDate, although you can use a scalar type for the attribute in Data Model Inspector (the right pane, right most tab).

Either way, that date type will contain the full date information -- both date and time.

If you just want to print the time, you can do something like the following:

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];

NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.dateFormat = @"hh:mm:ss";
NSString *timeString = [formatter stringFromDate:now];
NSLog(@"time:%@", timeString);
// prints: time:03:02:21
```

If you just need to print the time, do so. If you need to store the time string on the Core Data entity as well, then you will need to add a String attribute for that.

Comment: Ok Thanks I will save the time as string